# posix_fallocate() failed: Operation not permitted while opening .realm file

Tags: realm, serverless

I get the below error when i try to open and download .realm file in /tmp directory of serverless framework.
    {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: posix_fallocate() failed: Operation not permitted" }

```
Below is the code:

let realm = new Realm({path: '/tmp/custom.realm', schema: [schema1, schema2]});
realm.write(() => {
                console.log('completed==');
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: this might soon be finally fixed in Realm-Core: [see issue 4957](https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/4957).

---

In case you'll run into this problem elsewhere, here's a workaround.

This caused by AWS Lambda not supporting the `fallocate` and `fallocate64` system calls. Instead of returning the correct error code in this case, which would be `EINVAL` for *not supported on this file system*, Amazon has blocked the system call so that it returns `EPERM`. Realm-Core has code that handles `EINVAL` return value correctly but will be bewildered by the unexpected `EPERM` returned from the system call.

The solution is to add a small shared library as a layer to the lambda: compile the following C file on Linux machine or inside lambda-ci Docker image:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int posix_fallocate(int __fd, off_t __offset, off_t __len) {
    return EINVAL;
}

int posix_fallocate64(int __fd, off_t __offset, off_t __len) {
    return EINVAL;
}
```

1. Now, compile this to a shared object with something like

   ```
   gcc -shared fix.c -o fix.so
   ```
2. Then add it to a root of a ZIP file:

   ```
   zip layer.zip fix.so
   ```
3. Create a new lambda layer from this zip
4. Add the lambda layer to your lambda function
5. Finally make the shared object be loaded by configuring the environment value `LD_PRELOAD` with value `/opt/fix.so` to your Lambda.
6. Enjoy.

Comment: We have encountered similar problem in running wasm-ld, and this solution work as well.